# Bottom-up CXF Web Service with WS-Trust - is it possible?

Tags: cxf, ws-security, jbossfuse, fuseesb

I'm trying to develop a secure CXF web service with a java-first approach (java2ws).
All is fine until I try to define a "IssuedToken" policy as shown, for example, [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.1/html/Apache_CXF_Security_Guide/STS-Demo.html#STS-Demo-ServerWsdl).

The problem is, of course, that the WSDL is generated, so I can't insert the policy in the WSDL. I tried with the [@Policy](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.2.1/html/Apache_CXF_Development_Guide/JAXWSServiceDevJavaFirstAnnotate.html#JAXWSServiceDevJavaFirstAnnotateCxf) annotation and managed to generate a proper WSDL file, only to find that the policy is ignored by the service, which doesn't even show it in the "online" WSDL.

So how do I go about implementing a secure web service with a bottom-up approach? Can it be done?

P.S. I'm going to deploy the service in fuse

Comment: I think it's not possible this way. As per http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-trust.html _Note: Because the WS-IssuedToken support builds on the WS-SecurityPolicy support, this is currently only available to "wsdl first" projects._

Comment: You're right, thank you for pointing me to the paragraph in the docs. If you post an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not possible this way. As per [WS-Thrust](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-trust.html) *Note: Because the WS-IssuedToken support builds on the WS-SecurityPolicy support, this is currently only available to "wsdl first" projects.*